# Ngtemplate with out grunt or glup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a build process without grunt or glup and want to need to have ngtemplate because the team uses it but cant find an independent package for it but im willing to make one in the new system just need a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple js script that iterates through all directories except **node_modules** or **bower_components** and reads the file with .html extension and appends the content to the file **templates.js**
your templates.js may look like this

```
angular.module('templates').run(['$templateCache', 
  function($templateCache) {
     $templateCache.put('filename1','filecontent1');
     $templateCache.put('filename2','filecontent2');
  }]);
```

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.